# How to solve polymer command not found error

Tags: node.js, npm, polymer

Recently, I started to learn `polymer` framework but when I install to `polymer-cli` and then start polymer serve everything works great, next day, when I open the project and write `polymer serve`, terminal says `polymer command not found`.

I searched online and find that npm default directory error and follow steps to manually set it up again. Here is the steps, I have to write every morning;

**Make a directory for global installations:**

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

**Configure npm to use the new directory path:**

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

**Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:**

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

**Back on the command line, update your system variables:**

```
source ~/.profile
Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.

npm install -g jshint

npm install polymer-cli 
polymer serve
```

Then I am good to go. I am able to work on polymer again, but next day, I have to go through each steps otherwise it is not working. Do I have to write these commands everyday? Are there any absolute solution for this problem?

Comment: reformat the code

Comment: reformat the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to re- install `Polymer command line interface (Polymer-cli)` globally with `-g` flag

```
npm install -g polymer-cli
```

with above command, polymer-cli will be installed at `C:\Users\<user-id>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

In order to go step by step here the link : https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli

Comment: I already installed polymer with using that link in offical website. Problem is, when I want to continue my project tomorrow, and when I typed "polymer serve" to start it is saying again "polymer command not found".

Comment: I think the problem is not polymer own problem. try to setup system paths and variable with this link: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Likewise, I assumed there is a path problem with npm. I am using macosX I will search for this problem, let see if I can solve with changing those.

Comment: This may help.:  https://hathaway.cc/2008/06/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac/